# Using Assembly dosbox and loop

Tags: assembly

How do you make this program using loop?, I have finished making a loop for A123*B123*C123*, but I do not understand how to make a loop for the X's
A123*B123*C123*

```
  X

  XX

  XXX

  XXXX

  XXXXX
```

Code for A123* loop:

```
main    proc 
    mov cx, 3
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 'A'
outer:  int 21h
    push dx

    mov dl, '1'
    int 21h

    mov dl, '2'
    int 21h

    mov dl, '3'
    int 21h

    mov dl, '*'
    int 21h 

    pop dx
    inc dl
    loop outer
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? "This" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is that

- A123, B123, etc.. is a single dimensioned problem requiring a single loop.  A single loop whose body does each line and an increment to move from 'A' to 'B', etc..
- Whereas the X's is a two dimensioned problem requiring two loops.  An outer loop whose body does lines, like the above, yet with an inner loop (nested within the body of the outer loop) that does X's.  The outer loop informs the inner loop of how many X's to print for any given line.

The basic construct of a loop within a loop (nested loop) allows for two dimensional constructs, like traversing a matrix, a game board, and here a varying count of X's on each line.

---

We're talking about algorithms here, and you can probably study them easier in a language you already know well; you don't have to think in assembly to develop an algorithm.  Making an assembly version is much easier when you already know what the code should do, compared to writing an algorithm from scratch in assembly when you don't know it very well.